# Issue with golang.org/x/sys/unix missing function body

Tags: linux, docker, go, continuous-integration, bitbucket

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: golang:1.9

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - PACKAGE_PATH="${GOPATH}/src/bitbucket.org/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}"
          - mkdir -pv "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - tar -cO --exclude-vcs --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml . | tar -xv -C "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - cd "${PACKAGE_PATH}"
          - go version
          - uname -a
          - make build_linux
          - go test -v ./...`enter code here`
```

I try to build Golang app on Bitbucket CI but got the error with golang.org/x/sys/unix:

```
make build_linux
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build --tags "json1" -ldflags "-s -X main.version=0.63" -a -installsuffix cgo -o dbcore_linux ./cmd/dbcore/dbcore.go
# bitbucket.org/xxx/dbcore/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go:20:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go:24:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux_amd64_gc.go:13:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:12:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:13:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:14:6: missing function body
vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix_gc.go:15:6: missing function body
make: *** [build_linux] Error 2
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'build_linux' failed
```

Dockerfile:
https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/2f2f3b620d61f533484f24a568c2ca46e4fda91c/1.9/stretch/Dockerfile

I haven't issue on the local machine with MacOS. Only CI. How could I resolve that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a bad install of Go. You should check that the step that installs go succeeded. Maybe try a fresh install.

Comment: @Marc CI use default docker image with Golang 1.9, what could be wrong there?

Comment: It depends. If it installs it by extracting the tarball, it could have failed in the middle, this wouldn't be the first time. Have you actually checked the install? What happens if you ssh into the machine and try to build something? What happens if you grab a fresh tarball and try to use that?

Comment: It appears that for some reason your installation doesn't want to compile the assembler files that are in the syscall package. All the "missing function body" refer to functions implemented in assembler

Comment: You need to get the repo manually. Run `go get -u golang.org/x/sys` or clone the repository from [https://github.com/golang/sys](https://github.com/golang/sys) then copy it manually to vendor directory `bitbucket.org/xxx/dbcore/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/`

Comment: well, nothing helps

Comment: Have you checked the vendored package to see if the assembler files exist?

Comment: @JimB Thanks! I've checked repo and noticed *.s had been ignored in .gitignore and that's why I had the error. Now everything OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang `dep` command copy many files to the vendor folder which I wanted to skip with .gitignore rules, so *.s files had been also skipped for vendor/golang.org/x/sys/* dep.

Issue disappear after I exclude *.s files from .gitignore.

Comment: This issue was also helpful: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51091